# xpath for getting table rows with missing cell images

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use Xpath to grab in rows of a table containing images and text. Things work fine as long as images are present [as on this 3rd table on this page](https://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support/help-desk/view-article/99-how-to-insert-images-into-your-html-table-the-right-way).  But when images are missing as in the table [as on this page](https://www.patentati.it/quiz-patente-b/lista-domande/segnaletica-orizzontale-ostacoli/strisce-strada.html) it doesn't work. I need to connect the image with the right row of table data.

Here's the type of xpath_query strings I've been using in google sheets, where A1 contains the url.

```
=importXML(A1,"//tbody//img/@src")
=importXML(A1,"//tbody//tr")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exact output you want to get? Can you clarify?

Comment: When I wrote "I need to connect the image with the right row of table data" I meant, for example, that I need to know that the image in row 3 goes with the text in row 3, etc... for each row. In other words, I want to reproduce the table as it looks, within a spreadsheet. As it stands now, I can't do that -- the missing images cause some images and row text to become misaligned, appearing on different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter alternative with XPath filtering (url in `C2`, formula in `I27`) :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"figura:";IMAGE("https://www.patentati.it/"&IMPORTXML(C2;"//tr//img/@src|//tr[not(.//img)]/td[@class='domanda']"))}\QUERY(IMPORTHTML(C2;"table";1);"select Col2,Col3")})
```

Output :

[image: Output]

Sidenote : I'm based in Europe. Formula for US locales :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"figura:";IMAGE("https://www.patentati.it/"&IMPORTXML(C2,"//tr//img/@src|//tr[not(.//img)]/td[@class='domanda']"))},QUERY(IMPORTHTML(C2,"table",1),"select Col2,Col3")})
```

Comment: I've now tested this solution on 7 pages with different numbers of images present or missing, and it works everytime. Therefore, even though I appreciate all that I learned from @player0 I have to mark this as the correct answer.  Also, it seems (at least to me, the simplest). (By the way, only the US version worked for me; even though I'm in Europe, I must have things still configured US). Both of you have taught me a lot. I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Your solution works great one at a time. But when I try to execute this call on 30 different links in one sheet it takes over 30 minutes (I don't know exactly because I'm still waiting). Any suggestion on to how to manage this? I tried looking here but it didn't help me: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/#13

Comment: That's because you have to many `IMPORTXML` and `IMPORTHTML` functions on the same sheet. Besides reducing the number of links, I don't think you can do anything about it. You can have a look at `IMPORTFROMWEB` addon which might support more requests (you'll need to learn the basics (using `baseSelector`). List of pricing : https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/pricing/

Comment: `IMPORTFROMWEB` syntax : `=ARRAYFORMULA({{"figura:";IMAGE("https://www.patentati.it/"&IMPORTXML(C2,"//tr//img/@src|//tr[not(.//img)]/td[@class='domanda']"))},{IMPORTFROMWEB(C2,"//td[@class='domanda' or .='Domanda']")},{IMPORTFROMWEB(C2,"//td[@class='risp' or .='Risposta']")}})`

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE("https://www.patentati.it"&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(
 SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A1), 500, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches '.*zoomImage.*|.*rowspan.*'"), 
 "src=""(.+png)"), "♀♫"),,9^9), "♫")), "♀", ))))
```

[image]

---

and a whole table:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"figura"; IMAGE("https://www.patentati.it"&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(
 SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A1), 500, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches '.*zoomImage.*|.*rowspan.*'"), 
 "src=""(.+png)"), "♀♫"),,9^9), "♫")), "♀", )))}, 
 QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 1), "select Col2,Col3", 0)})
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This answer is so over the top, I can hardly believe it. My question seemed so simple, but I guess I had no idea. So, I'm impressed. Thank you. On the other hand, I see no way to apply this to other cases. Getting the text is so easy, but matching the text with the images is apparently in a whole 'nother realm. Is there any easier way I can match the images with the row text? I don't need elegant. Thanks again.

Comment: web scraping into google sheets is rarely generic. most sites are full of JS elements so its really individual for every single site. (in 1999 you would get everything via simple xPath/IMPORTXML). this answer uses directly the source code (via IMPORTDATA) of the site to get those images on the right row

Comment: I see you know what you are talking about, but can you please try to consider something very simple: It seems to me the command I was using, =importXML(A1,"//tbody//img/@src"), caused rows to be skipped because there was no <img src attribute in that row. Therefore, if there were a way to have it find something else in that row, just to fill that gap, then all the images would go to the proper row. I know this is a 'hack' but I'm just not at the level you are and this is all I need for now. Simple can be a beautiful thing when you're not an expert.  Thanks.

Comment: thats exactly whats happening there. your short IMPORTXML formula is equivalent to https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLLZr.png. and to include skipped rows we just add `|.*rowspan.*` in query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27yLC.png